# Constrain return type from argument function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function taking a function as an argument. The argument function returns one of a few enums. How do I infer the type of the wrapper function by using the return type of the argument function.

I think much easier explained as an example:

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: '2' }

function h(k: (() => 'a' | 'b')) {
  return foo[k()]
}

const d = h(() => 'a') 
// expected: d should be of type number
//   actual: d is of type number | string
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeMCGAuGBGAGhgCNcByAJjJgF8AoOuAVzGCgEtwYALACgGtcvXgEoUAPhhlM1AD5TiZEWLR0YMAE4BTKEw1h4iANr9RAXTr06oSLAAmKHsLHJJ0pTDoB6LzC0APAActNi07XAcIbhAmABsHYi0YEDgYKABPYJgwJgBbRI1vX3VMNiZMWIiYdghk1IysnPytDRh5aA12MABzIA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define returned key type as generic parameter (it will be inferred as a single key and not union of all possible keys):

```
function h<K extends keyof typeof foo>(k: (() => K)) {
  return foo[k()]
}

const d = h(() => 'a') // now number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeMCGAuGBGAGhgCNcByAJjJgF8BYAKEbgFcxgoBLcGACwB4A0jACmADygiwAEwgwA1iICeIODChKADiNXxEAPgAU83IcMBKFPpiDzltIxgwATiKgtnYPSADa8iwC6jPRMDKCQsNIofGaWyNZkmGSWAPQpMGAgAO4ZLAC2xCLOQA)

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround / solution but it's not pretty

```
function h<T extends (() => 'a' | 'b')>(k: T) {
  return foo[k()] as typeof foo[ReturnType<T>]
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeMCGAuGBGAGhgCNcByAJjJgF8AoOuAVzGCgEtwYALAHgBUYAUwAeUIWAAmEGAApZAShQA+GGUzUAPmuJkFy2QGtc-JWjowYAJyFQmVsPEQBtQ4oC6WGVACeAByEQOCcQZwAlW3swfn8hAWV3Ono6UEhYSRQeeSVkVXU9GCA)